# ¿Cual es la mejor manera de factorizar un IF? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi pregunta realmente es muy sencilla, ¿Que otras maneras puedo usar para reducir mi codigo? o que seria lo ideal para utilizar y reemplazar el IF, esto con la finalidad de aprender. Bueno esta es mi sentencia If con la que estoy trabajando:

```
/*  VERIFICA SI EXISTE LA MATRIZ  */
    DECLARE @curso varchar(max)
    if @cur_clave_str = '639' or @cur_clave_str = '645' or @cur_clave_str = '961' or @cur_clave_str = '730' or @cur_clave_str = '642'
    or @cur_clave_str = '2281' or @cur_clave_str = '998' or @cur_clave_str='989' or @cur_clave_str='643'
        set @curso = (select Val from tblMatrices where ID=@cur_clave_str)          
    else 
        set @curso = @cur_clave_str
```

Este sentencia if se ejecuta dentro de un SP el cual recibe como parametro la variable @cur_clave_str y de esta variable valida con mi sentencia IF si existe el Id en mi tabla tblMatrices, si existe me guarda en la variable @curso el Valor de la columna Val del registro que encontro y en caso contrario solo setea el valor agregado en el parametro @cur_clave_str a la variable @curso.

Comment: Es idea mía, o esta pregunta está basada en opiniones? Peeeero los moderadores están en huelga, así que tal vez tome algo de tiempo antes de ser cerrada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La única mejoría que veo para ese código en cuanto a facilitar la interpretación, es utilizar IN en vez de las múltiples condiciones. Es importante notar que al momento de que se compile, SQL Server va a interpretar el IN como el código original.

```
/*  VERIFICA SI EXISTE LA MATRIZ  */
DECLARE @curso varchar(max)
IF @cur_clave_str IN( '639', '645', '961', '730', '642', '2281', '998', '989', '643')
    SET @curso = (select Val from tblMatrices where ID = @cur_clave_str);       
ELSE 
    SET @curso = @cur_clave_str;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Saludos.**

Toda vez que todas tus condiciones son inclusivas para cualquier valor te sugiero usar `IN`; de esta forma tendrás solo una vez `@cur_clave_str IN ([los valores])`.